# Results/topics on p-adic number theory analysis understandable by undergraduates

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I've been reading about p-adic analysis lately, and am interested to work on a specific topic about it for my undergraduate thesis. However, almost all dissertations I've read online are too hard to grasp for an undergraduate.

Topics on p-adic hodge theory, p-adic etale cohomology, p-adic L functions, p-adic application on number theory cryptography, and perfectoid spaces are some interesting topics on p-adic. But those are quite out of reach for most of us, I would like to know if there had been any interesting results about those that could be stated and/or worked on by an undergraduate?

If not, could you suggest any results/consequences on p-adic workable by an undergraduate?

Thank you!

Comment: how about Dwork's proof of the rationality of the zeta function? See, for instance, https://www.amazon.com/Numbers-Analysis-Zeta-Functions-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387960171/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1543368223&sr=8-4&keywords=padic+analysis

Comment: And here is a version of the previous on line:http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.461.4588&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://mathoverflow.net/q/81342. A list of elementary results using p-adic analysis.